# Setting up nginx and apache httpd

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver, nginx, httpd

Suppose I have nginx + php (fastcgi) running on domain.local:80/443
and Apache HTTPD server running on domain.local:8000/4430

Is there a way to configure nginx to reverse_proxy http(s) requests to
Apache.domain.local to the Apache server

Comment: I'm guessing this would be on RHEL/CentOS?

Comment: I have a Archliunx server